# figsize does not work for matplotlib 3d plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plotted 2 figures, here is the screenshot

[figsize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXnmn.png)

the one (2D) on top is rendered as expected.
the one (3D) on bottom is not, the figure is so small!

setting the value of `figsize` does not work.

figsize=(3,3) and figsize=(13,13) give the same result!

`%matplotlib inline` rendered same way.

I tried different browsers, clear the cache, dose not work either.

I guess some rcParams control this, because this is reproducible only on my mac, but I don't have a clue to find it!

any clue will be appreciated.

whole coding:

```
%pylab inline
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, marker = '^')
```

Comment: Setting the figure size works fine for me. I would suggest you open a new notebook and produce a [mcve] inside of it to make sure there are no interactions with previous code.

Comment: So when you try something like `figsize=(13,13)` instead, the result is the same?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest yes

Comment: Maybe some brower cache problem, like it will always show the same figure, even if code changes?

Comment: The rcParam to control figure size is `plt.rcParam["figure.figsize"]` you may indeed print that to see what it's set to or change it and see what happens. However, it shouldn't matter, because the `figsize` inside `figure` would take precedence over the rcParam settings.

Answer (score 3):

As of notebook version 5.7.4, on MacOS 10.14.2 and Chrome 71.0.3578.98, this problem persists but can be fixed with `%matplotlib inline` setting by using the magic command

`%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}`

as given in the documentation [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html).

[Correctly funcitoning example](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/paultopia/54e614e4925361a94c3af79957d29efb).

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug in Jupyter.
As a quick fix, you can use the notebook- instead of the inline-backend for matplotlib.
To do so, replace `%matplotlib inline` with `%matplotlib notebook`.

Comment: hmm... I had the same problem, and this fix doesn't work for me as of jupyter 4.4.0 on macos

Comment: failing example: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/paultopia/e0609e25ac113a49e65e7be95a9bbe45

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading matplotlib from version 3.0.0 to 3.0.2 solved the problem. If you use pip type:

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

I verified the case with Jupyter version 4.4.0.